# Prove or disprove: the spectral radius of a matrix with negative entries and row sums as 1 is larger than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We all know that the spectral radius of a stochastic matrix is $1$. But how's the "negative" proposition: For a matrix $M=(m_{ij})_{n\times n}$, if there exists $m_{ij}<0$ for some $1\le i,j\le n$ and $Me=e$ where $e$ is a vector with all entries being $1$, the spectral radius $\rho(M)>1$. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: the conditions seem to be too general so the answer turns to be trivial. I've posted another question at [About the spectral radius of a kind of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/364427/11014) which is closer to the actual problem I've met. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the matrix:
$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & -1 \\
2 & -1 \end{array} \right)$. It has two eigenvectors, $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$, with respective eigenvalues $1$ and $0$.

Comment: Hmm...the problem I've actually met seems to have some implied constraints. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've updated the question at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/364427/11014